# Calling curl in Scala

Tags: java, scala, curl, solr

I'm using scala to insert Document to Solr. I can run

```
s"$solrPath/bin/solr create -c newDB" !
```

in Scala to create a new database called newDB. Next I want to add fields to the db so I write

```
"curl http://localhost:8983/solr/firma/schema -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{\"add-field\":{\"name\":\"Website\",\"type\":\"text_de\",\"stored\":\"true\",\"indexed\":\"true\"}}'" !
```

but when I ran it, it shows me something like

**% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed**

**100   163    0    79  100    84  10730  11409 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 28000**

**{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "errors":"no stream"}**

in the console, I have no idea what "no stream" means. But if run the "curl..." in console directly, there will be no problem.

Can anyone help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO the right syntax for that is

```
val solr = Seq("curl", "http://localhost:8983/solr/firma/schema", "-X", "POST", "-H" ...)
solr !!
```